# Как сделать функцию продолжения и началом процесса заново в PyQt5?

Tags: python, ооп, pyqt5, qpushbutton, qsettings

У меня есть код, на котором если производятся какие либо действия они сохраняются, но мне нужно сделать функцию "Начать с начала", где при нажатии такой кнопки прогресс сбрасывался, и чтобы была кнопка "Продолжить".

Обновление:

У меня есть кнопки "Начать с начала" и "Продолжить", мне нужно, чтобы при нажатии кнопки продолжить игра продолжалась с того места, где остановился пользователь, а при нажатии кнопки "Начать с начала", чтобы она начинала с начала, как это реализовать?

мой код:

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets, QtGui, QtCore, QtMultimedia
from PyQt5.Qt import *

russia_language = True

try:
    from PyQt5.QtWinExtras import QtWin
    myappid = 'mycompany.myproduct.subproduct.version'
    QtWin.setCurrentProcessExplicitAppUserModelID(myappid)
except ImportError:
    pass


class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        filename = 'music.mp3'
        fullpath = QtCore.QDir.current().absoluteFilePath(filename)
        url = QtCore.QUrl.fromLocalFile(fullpath)
        content = QtMultimedia.QMediaContent(url)
        self.player = QtMultimedia.QMediaPlayer()
        self.player.setMedia(content)
        self.player.setVolume(50)
        self.player.play()

        self.slider = QSlider(Qt.Horizontal, self)
        self.slider.setRange(0, 100)
        self.slider.setValue(50)
        self.slider.setGeometry(800, 720, 300, 70)
        self.slider.hide()
        self.slider.valueChanged.connect(self.player.setVolume)

        def Button(btn_name, text, color1, px, resize, resize_2, move, move_2, color, mains):
            btn_name.setMouseTracking(True);
            btn_name.setText(text)
            btn_name.setStyleSheet(
                "background-color: " + color1 + "; color: " + color + "; border-radius: " + str(px) + "px")
            btn_name.setFont(QtGui.QFont('MS Serif', 14))
            btn_name.resize(resize, resize_2)
            btn_name.move(move, move_2)
            btn_name.clicked.connect(mains)

        def Button_2(btn_name, text, px, resize, resize_2, move, move_2, color, size):
            btn_name.setMouseTracking(True);
            btn_name.setText(text)
            btn_name.setStyleSheet(
                "color: " + color + "; border-radius: " + str(px) + "px")
            btn_name.setFont(QtGui.QFont('Gabriola', size))
            btn_name.resize(resize, resize_2)
            btn_name.move(move, move_2)
            # btn_name.clicked.connect(mains)

        def Button_3(btn_name, text, px, resize, resize_2, move, move_2, color, mains):
            btn_name.setMouseTracking(True);
            if text == "Настройки громкости":
                btn_name.setCheckable(True)
                btn_name.setText(f'{text}: ({self.slider.value()})')
            else:
                btn_name.setText(text)
            # +++ ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

            btn_name.setStyleSheet(
                "color: " + color + "; border-radius: " + str(px) + "px")
            btn_name.setFont(QtGui.QFont('MS Serif', 14))
            btn_name.resize(resize, resize_2)
            btn_name.move(move, move_2)
            btn_name.clicked.connect(mains)

        def Image(lbl_name, move_1, move_2, resize_1, resize_2):
            lbl_name.setPixmap(self.pix)
            lbl_name.move(move_1, move_2)
            lbl_name.resize(resize_1, resize_2)

        self.lbl2 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self)

        self.pix = QtGui.QPixmap("image.jpg")
        Image(self.lbl2, 0, 0, 1920, 1080)

        self.lbl1 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self)
        self.pix = QtGui.QPixmap("System_image/textbox.png")
        Image(self.lbl1, 0, 800, 1920, 300)
        self.btn1 = QPushButton(self)
        Button_2(self.btn1, "Вы появились в неизвестном вам месте,\nгде было невероятно красиво", 10, 1000, 200, 430, 830, "White", 30)
        self.inv = QtWidgets.QLabel(self)
        self.pix = QtGui.QPixmap("Button_image/inventory_btn.png")
        Image(self.inv, -30, 600, 156, 96)
        self.btn31 = QPushButton(self)
        Button_3(self.btn31, "", 0, 100, 100, 0, 600, "White", self.inventory)
        self.inv_open = QtWidgets.QLabel(self)
        self.pix = QtGui.QPixmap("Button_image/inventory.png")
        Image(self.inv_open, 70, 40, 1770, 996)
        self.inv_open.close()
        self.btn4 = QPushButton(self)
        Button_3(self.btn4, "", 5, 100, 100, 1650, 110, "White", self.inventory_close)
        self.btn4.close()
        self.lbl20 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self)
        self.pix = QtGui.QPixmap("System_image/Selection_menu.png")
        Image(self.lbl20, 0, 0, 1920, 1080)
        self.lbl20.close()
        self.mg_open = QtWidgets.QLabel(self)
        self.pix = QtGui.QPixmap("Button_image/Magazine.png")
        Image(self.mg_open, -30, 480, 156, 96)
        self.btn5 = QPushButton(self)
        Button_3(self.btn5, "", 0, 100, 100, 0, 480, "White", self.event_log)
        self.btn6 = QPushButton(self)
        Button_3(self.btn6, "", 0, 460, 800, 160, 170, "White", self.notes)
        self.btn6.close()
        self.btn7 = QPushButton(self)
        Button_3(self.btn7, "", 0, 460, 800, 700, 170, "White", self.easter)
        self.btn7.close()
        self.btn8 = QPushButton(self)
        Button_3(self.btn8, "", 0, 460, 800, 1260, 170, "White", self.tasks)
        self.btn8.close()
        self.notes_open = QtWidgets.QLabel(self)
        self.pix = QtGui.QPixmap("The_event_log/Notes.png")
        Image(self.notes_open, 0, 0, 1920, 1080)
        self.notes_open.close()
        self.btn9 = QPushButton(self)
        Button_3(self.btn9, "", 5, 80, 80, 1730, 50, "White", self.inventory_close)
        self.btn9.close()
        self.easter_open = QtWidgets.QLabel(self)
        self.pix = QtGui.QPixmap("The_event_log/Easter.png")
        Image(self.easter_open, 0, 0, 1920, 1080)
        self.easter_open.close()
        self.btn10 = QPushButton(self)
        Button_3(self.btn10, "", 5, 80, 80, 1730, 50, "White", self.inventory_close)
        self.btn10.close()

        self.tasks_open = QtWidgets.QLabel(self)
        self.pix = QtGui.QPixmap("The_event_log/Tasks.png")
        Image(self.tasks_open, 0, 0, 1920, 1080)
        self.tasks_open.close()
        self.btn11 = QPushButton(self)
        Button_3(self.btn11, "", 5, 80, 80, 1730, 50, "White", self.inventory_close)
        self.btn11.close()

        self.lbl2.close()
        self.btn31.close()
        self.btn1.close()
        self.lbl1.close()
        self.inv.close()
        self.mg_open.close()
        self.btn5.close()
        self.btn6.close()

        self.btn_start = QPushButton(self)
        Button_3(self.btn_start, "Начать заново", 20, 300, 100, 800, 400, "Black", self.start)

        self.btn_next = QPushButton(self)
        Button_3(self.btn_next, "Продолжить", 20, 300, 100, 800, 500, "Black", self.start)
        # !!!
        self.btn_select = QPushButton(self)
        Button_3(self.btn_select, "Настройки громкости", 20, 300, 100, 800, 600, "Black", self.volume_custom)

    def inventory(self):
        self.btn31.close()
        self.btn1.close()
        self.lbl1.close()
        self.inv.close()
        self.inv_open.show()
        self.btn4.show()
        self.mg_open.close()
        self.btn5.close()
        self.btn6.close()

    def inventory_close(self):
        self.btn1.show()
        self.lbl1.show()
        self.inv.show()
        self.inv_open.close()
        self.btn4.close()
        self.notes_open.close()
        self.btn9.close()
        self.mg_open.show()
        self.btn5.show()
        self.btn6.close()
        self.btn7.close()
        self.btn8.close()
        self.easter_open.close()
        self.btn10.close()
        self.btn11.close()
        self.tasks_open.close()
        self.btn31.show()

    def animations(self):
        animation = QPropertyAnimation(self)
        animation.setTargetObject(self.btn_name)
        animation.setPropertyName(b'pos')
        animation.setStartValue(QPoint(250, -200))
        animation.setEndValue(QPoint(250, 0))
        animation.setDuration(500)
        animation.start()

    def event_log(self):
        self.btn31.close()
        self.btn1.close()
        self.lbl1.close()
        self.inv.close()
        self.btn5.close()
        self.mg_open.close()
        self.lbl20.show()
        self.btn6.show()
        self.btn7.show()
        self.btn8.show()

    def notes(self):
        self.lbl20.close()
        self.notes_open.show()
        self.btn9.show()
        self.btn6.close()
        self.btn7.close()
        self.btn8.close()

    def easter(self):
        self.lbl20.close()
        self.easter_open.show()
        self.btn10.show()
        self.btn6.close()
        self.btn7.close()
        self.btn8.close()

    def tasks(self):
        self.lbl20.close()
        self.tasks_open.show()
        self.btn11.show()
        self.btn6.close()
        self.btn7.close()
        self.btn8.close()

    # !!!
    def start(self):
        self.btn_next.close()
        self.btn1.show()
        self.lbl1.show()
        self.inv.show()
        self.inv_open.close()
        self.btn4.close()
        self.notes_open.close()
        self.btn9.close()
        self.mg_open.show()
        self.btn5.show()
        self.btn6.close()
        self.btn7.close()
        self.btn8.close()
        self.easter_open.close()
        self.btn10.close()
        self.btn11.close()
        self.tasks_open.close()
        self.btn31.show()
        self.lbl2.show()
        self.slider.close()
        self.btn_select.close()
        self.btn_start.close()

    # !!!
    # +++ vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv
    def volume_custom(self):
        # тут действие, но я поставил print что бы не выдавал ошибку
        sender = self.sender()
        print(f'def volume_custom(): {sender.text()} - {sender.isChecked()}')

        if sender.isChecked():
            self.slider.show()
        else:
            self.slider.close()

        sender.setText(f'Настройки громкости: ({self.slider.value()})')


# +++ ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    app.setWindowIcon(QtGui.QIcon('System_image/icon.png'))
    ex = MainWindow()
    ex.setWindowTitle('Story Telling')
    ex.setWindowIcon(QIcon('System_image/icon.png'))
    ex.showFullScreen()
    ex.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: TFader, пожалуйста объясните лучше, что вы хотите сделать? В заголовке вы говорите о функции, которая должна организовать работу какого-то `процесса`. Что вы собираетесь делать в этом процессе? В теле вопроса вы говорите о работе какого-то `прогресса`. Как связаны между собой  `процесс` и `прогресс`? и как это все связано с действиями по сохранению расположению окна и лабел в вашем приложении.

Comment: я хочу добавить кнопки "Начать заново" и "Продолжить", я использовал код с предыдущего вопроса, но там код все время сохранялся, даже если я создам новый файл и вставлю туда этот код, он продолжится автоматически, возможно ли как то совместить их?

Comment: TFader, добавьте в тело вашего вопроса подробности, о которых вы пишите в комментариях и ссылку на вопрос,, в котором код для объединения с текущим вопросом. И еще раз попытайтесь рассказать что вы хотите сделать. Попробуйте как-то на изображении показать расположение виджетов в окне приложения, которое вы хотите получить.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я не уверен что правильно понял вас, но предложу вам попробовать следующее решение:

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets, QtGui, QtCore
from PyQt5.Qt import *

CONFIG_FILE_NAME = 'config_q1368766.ini'  


class PushButton(QPushButton):
    def __init__(self, text, parent=None):
        super(PushButton, self).__init__(parent)

        self.setMouseTracking(True)
        self.setText(text)
        
        if len(text) == 1:                                                # +++
            self.setStyleSheet("""
                background-color: pink; 
                border-radius: 25px;
            """)
            self.setFont(QtGui.QFont("Pusia-Bold.otf", 30, QtGui.QFont.Bold))
            self.setFixedSize(50, 50)
        else:
            self.setStyleSheet("""
                background-color: yellow; 
            """)
            

class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.resize(1000, 600)
        self.num = 5
        self.text = None
        self._rect = QRect(0, 0, 100, 100)                                # +++

        self.сentralWidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(self)
        self.сentralWidget.setObjectName("сentralWidget")
        self.setCentralWidget(self.сentralWidget)

        self.widget_buttons = QWidget()
        self.widget_buttons.setStyleSheet("""
            background-color: #1E5F74; 
        """)
        layout = QGridLayout(self.widget_buttons)
        self.btn4 = PushButton("↑", self)
        layout.addWidget(self.btn4, 0, 1)

        self.btn1 = PushButton("←", self)
        layout.addWidget(self.btn1, 1, 0)
        self.btn2 = PushButton("→", self)
        layout.addWidget(self.btn2, 1, 2)
        self.btn3 = PushButton("↓", self)
        layout.addWidget(self.btn3, 2, 1)
        
# +++ vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv
        self.widget_buttons.hide()
       
        self.widget_buttons_start = QWidget()
        self.widget_buttons_start.setStyleSheet("""
            background-color: #1E5F74; 
        """)
        layout = QGridLayout(self.widget_buttons_start)
        self.start_over = PushButton("Начать с начала" , self)
        self.start_over.clicked.connect(self._start_over)
        
        layout.addWidget(self.start_over, 0, 0)        
        self.continue_game = PushButton("Продолжить", self)
        layout.addWidget(self.continue_game, 0, 1)  
        self.continue_game.clicked.connect(self._continue_game)        
# +++ ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

        main_layout = QVBoxLayout(self.сentralWidget)

        main_layout.addWidget(self.widget_buttons_start,                  # +++
                              alignment=Qt.AlignRight | Qt.AlignBottom)   # +++        
        
        main_layout.addWidget(self.widget_buttons,
                              alignment=Qt.AlignRight | Qt.AlignBottom)

        self.btn1.pressed.connect(lambda: self.btn_pressed('Влево'))
        self.btn1.released.connect(self.btn_released)
        self.btn2.pressed.connect(lambda: self.btn_pressed('Вправо'))
        self.btn2.released.connect(self.btn_released)
        self.btn3.pressed.connect(lambda: self.btn_pressed('Вниз'))
        self.btn3.released.connect(self.btn_released)
        self.btn4.pressed.connect(lambda: self.btn_pressed('Вехр'))
        self.btn4.released.connect(self.btn_released)

        self.lbl1 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.сentralWidget)
        self.pix = QtGui.QPixmap("Ok.png").scaled(100, 100)
        self.lbl1.setPixmap(self.pix)
        self.lbl1.setGeometry(self._rect)
        
        self.lbl1.hide()                                                  # +++

        self.timer = QTimer()
        self.timer.timeout.connect(self.on_clicked)
        self.timer.setInterval(10)

        self.load_settings()  

# +++ vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv
    def _start_over(self):
        self.lbl1.setGeometry(self._rect)
        self.widget_buttons_start.hide()
        self.widget_buttons.show()
        self.lbl1.show()
        
    def _continue_game(self):
        self.widget_buttons_start.hide()
        self.widget_buttons.show()
        self.lbl1.show()
# +++ ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

    def btn_pressed(self, text):
        self.text = text
        self.timer.start()

    def btn_released(self):
        self.timer.stop()

    def on_clicked(self):
        if self.text == "Влево":
            x, y = self.lbl1.pos().x(), self.lbl1.pos().y()
            x = x - self.num if x - self.num > 0 else 0
            self.lbl1.move(x, y)
        elif self.text == "Вправо":
            x, y = self.lbl1.pos().x(), self.lbl1.pos().y()
            w = self.size().width() - self.lbl1.size().width()
            x = x + self.num \
                if x + self.num < w else w
            self.lbl1.move(x, y)

        elif self.text == "Вниз":
            x, y = self.lbl1.pos().x(), self.lbl1.pos().y()
            h = self.size().height() - self.lbl1.size().height()  # !!!
            y = y + self.num if y + self.num < h else h  # !!!
            self.lbl1.move(x, y)
        elif self.text == "Вехр":
            x, y = self.lbl1.pos().x(), self.lbl1.pos().y()
            h = self.size().height() - self.lbl1.size().height()  # !!!
            y = y - self.num if y - self.num > 0 else 0  # !!!
            self.lbl1.move(x, y)

    def load_settings(self):
        settings = QSettings(CONFIG_FILE_NAME, QSettings.IniFormat)
        geometry = settings.value('Geometry')
        if geometry:
            self.restoreGeometry(geometry)
        state = settings.value('WindowState')
        if state:
            self.restoreState(state)
        self.lbl1.setGeometry(settings.value('RectValue', QRect(0, 0, 100, 100)))

    def save_settings(self):
        settings = QSettings(CONFIG_FILE_NAME, QSettings.IniFormat)
        settings.setValue('Geometry', self.saveGeometry())
        settings.setValue('WindowState', self.saveState())
        settings.setValue('RectValue', self.lbl1.geometry())

    def closeEvent(self, event):
        self.save_settings()
        super().closeEvent(event)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = MainWindow()
    ex.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]