# Как в PyQt5 сделать сохранения и продолжение?

Tags: python, pyqt5, qpushbutton

Из прошлого вопроса ([Как сделать функцию продолжения и началом процесса заново в PyQt5?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1368978)) у меня появился код, который я пытался перенести на свой, но у меня не получилось, тот код был шаблоном, как сделать в другом коде такое как в прошлом вопросе указанном выше?
(К сожалению я не могу загрузить все скриншоты с описанием кнопок/картинок, они превышают допустимый размер. поэтому я загрузил их на Google Disk, вот ссылка https://drive.google.com/file/d/15fN4MzZ3hRXcw2EqBs170tObx4ce1PkO/view?usp=drivesdk)
Описание самих кнопок:

```
self.btn_start - кнопка "Начать заново" 
self.btn_next - кнопка "Продолжить" 
self.lbl2 - Картинка фона после нажатия кнопки Старт
self.lbl1 - Картинка чёрной полоски, где должен быть текст
self.lbl11 - Картинка кнопки "Далее"
self.btn1 - Кнопка с текстом "Вы появились... "
self.inv - Иконка инвентаря
self.btn31 - Кнопка инвентаря
self.inv_open - Картинка инвентаря, открывается при нажатии self.btn31
self.btn4 - Картинка закрытия инвентаря
self.mg_open, - Иконка журнала
self.btn5 - Кнопка журнала
self.lbl20 - Картинка выбора журнала (что именно открыть при нажатии кнопки self.btn5)
self.btn6, self.btn7 и self.btn8 - кнопки в выборе журнала (что именно открыть) 
self.btn9 - Кнопка закрытия если пользователь выбрал первый вариант в кнопках выше
self.notes_open - Картинка журнала если пользователь выбрал первый вариант в кнопках выше
self.easter_open - Картинка журнала если пользователь выбрал второй вариант в кнопках выше
self.btn10 - Кнопка закрытия журнала если пользователь выбрал второй вариант в кнопках выше
self.tasks_open - Картинка журнала если пользователь выбрал третий вариант в кнопках выше
self.btn11 - Кнопка закрытия журнала если пользователь выбрал третий вариант в кнопках выше
self.btn_select - Кнопка "Настройки громкости" в главном меню
self.slider - Сама настройка громкости (открывается и закрывается при нажатии на self.btn_select)
```

мой код:

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets, QtGui, QtCore, QtMultimedia
from PyQt5.Qt import *

try:
    from PyQt5.QtWinExtras import QtWin
    myappid = 'mycompany.myproduct.subproduct.version'
    QtWin.setCurrentProcessExplicitAppUserModelID(myappid)
except ImportError:
    pass


class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        filename = 'music.mp3'
        fullpath = QtCore.QDir.current().absoluteFilePath(filename)
        url = QtCore.QUrl.fromLocalFile(fullpath)
        content = QtMultimedia.QMediaContent(url)
        self.player = QtMultimedia.QMediaPlayer()
        self.player.setMedia(content)
        self.player.setVolume(50)
        self.player.play()

        self.slider = QSlider(Qt.Horizontal, self)
        self.slider.setRange(0, 100)
        self.slider.setValue(50)
        self.slider.setGeometry(800, 720, 300, 70)
        self.slider.hide()
        self.slider.valueChanged.connect(self.player.setVolume)

        def Button(btn_name, text, color1, px, resize, resize_2, move, move_2, color, mains):
            btn_name.setMouseTracking(True);
            btn_name.setText(text)
            btn_name.setStyleSheet(
                "background-color: " + color1 + "; color: " + color + "; border-radius: " + str(px) + "px")
            btn_name.setFont(QtGui.QFont('MS Serif', 14))
            btn_name.resize(resize, resize_2)
            btn_name.move(move, move_2)
            btn_name.clicked.connect(mains)

        def Button_2(btn_name, text, px, resize, resize_2, move, move_2, color, size):
            btn_name.setMouseTracking(True);
            btn_name.setText(text)
            btn_name.setStyleSheet(
                "color: " + color + "; border-radius: " + str(px) + "px")
            btn_name.setFont(QtGui.QFont('Gabriola', size))
            btn_name.resize(resize, resize_2)
            btn_name.move(move, move_2)
            # btn_name.clicked.connect(mains)

        def Button_3(btn_name, text, px, resize, resize_2, move, move_2, color, mains):
            btn_name.setMouseTracking(True);
            if text == "Настройки громкости":
                btn_name.setCheckable(True)
                btn_name.setText(f'{text}: ({self.slider.value()})')
            else:
                btn_name.setText(text)

            btn_name.setStyleSheet(
                "color: " + color + "; border-radius: " + str(px) + "px")
            btn_name.setFont(QtGui.QFont('MS Serif', 14))
            btn_name.resize(resize, resize_2)
            btn_name.move(move, move_2)
            btn_name.clicked.connect(mains)

        def Image(lbl_name, move_1, move_2, resize_1, resize_2):
            lbl_name.setPixmap(self.pix)
            lbl_name.move(move_1, move_2)
            lbl_name.resize(resize_1, resize_2)

        self.lbl2 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self)

        self.pix = QtGui.QPixmap("image.jpg")
        Image(self.lbl2, 0, 0, 1920, 1080)

        self.lbl1 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self)
        self.pix = QtGui.QPixmap("System_image/textbox.png")
        Image(self.lbl1, 0, 800, 1920, 300)
        self.lbl11 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self)
        self.pix = QtGui.QPixmap("Button_image/next.png")
        Image(self.lbl11, 1500, 930, 600, 200)
        self.lbl11.close()
        self.btn1 = QPushButton(self)
        Button_2(self.btn1, "Вы появились в неизвестном вам месте,\nгде было невероятно красиво", 10, 1000, 200, 430, 830, "White", 30)
        self.inv = QtWidgets.QLabel(self)
        self.pix = QtGui.QPixmap("Button_image/inventory_btn.png")
        Image(self.inv, -30, 600, 156, 96)
        self.btn31 = QPushButton(self)
        Button_3(self.btn31, "", 0, 100, 100, 0, 600, "White", self.inventory)
        self.inv_open = QtWidgets.QLabel(self)
        self.pix = QtGui.QPixmap("Button_image/inventory.png")
        Image(self.inv_open, 70, 40, 1770, 996)
        self.inv_open.close()
        self.btn4 = QPushButton(self)
        Button_3(self.btn4, "", 5, 100, 100, 1650, 110, "White", self.inventory_close)
        self.btn4.close()
        self.lbl20 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self)
        self.pix = QtGui.QPixmap("System_image/Selection_menu.png")
        Image(self.lbl20, 0, 0, 1920, 1080)
        self.lbl20.close()
        self.mg_open = QtWidgets.QLabel(self)
        self.pix = QtGui.QPixmap("Button_image/Magazine.png")
        Image(self.mg_open, -30, 480, 156, 96)
        self.btn5 = QPushButton(self)
        Button_3(self.btn5, "", 0, 100, 100, 0, 480, "White", self.event_log)
        self.btn6 = QPushButton(self)
        Button_3(self.btn6, "", 0, 460, 800, 160, 170, "White", self.notes)
        self.btn6.close()
        self.btn7 = QPushButton(self)
        Button_3(self.btn7, "", 0, 460, 800, 700, 170, "White", self.easter)
        self.btn7.close()
        self.btn8 = QPushButton(self)
        Button_3(self.btn8, "", 0, 460, 800, 1260, 170, "White", self.tasks)
        self.btn8.close()
        self.notes_open = QtWidgets.QLabel(self)
        self.pix = QtGui.QPixmap("The_event_log/Notes.png")
        Image(self.notes_open, 0, 0, 1920, 1080)
        self.notes_open.close()
        self.btn9 = QPushButton(self)
        Button_3(self.btn9, "", 5, 80, 80, 1730, 50, "White", self.inventory_close)
        self.btn9.close()
        self.easter_open = QtWidgets.QLabel(self)
        self.pix = QtGui.QPixmap("The_event_log/Easter.png")
        Image(self.easter_open, 0, 0, 1920, 1080)
        self.easter_open.close()
        self.btn10 = QPushButton(self)
        Button_3(self.btn10, "", 5, 80, 80, 1730, 50, "White", self.inventory_close)
        self.btn10.close()

        self.tasks_open = QtWidgets.QLabel(self)
        self.pix = QtGui.QPixmap("The_event_log/Tasks.png")
        Image(self.tasks_open, 0, 0, 1920, 1080)
        self.tasks_open.close()
        self.btn11 = QPushButton(self)
        Button_3(self.btn11, "", 5, 80, 80, 1730, 50, "White", self.inventory_close)
        self.btn11.close()

        self.lbl2.close()
        self.btn31.close()
        self.btn1.close()
        self.lbl1.close()
        self.inv.close()
        self.mg_open.close()
        self.btn5.close()
        self.btn6.close()

        self.btn_start = QPushButton(self)
        Button_3(self.btn_start, "Начать заново", 20, 300, 100, 800, 400, "Black", self.start)

        self.btn_next = QPushButton(self)
        Button_3(self.btn_next, "Продолжить", 20, 300, 100, 800, 500, "Black", self.next_start)

        self.btn_select = QPushButton(self)
        Button_3(self.btn_select, "Настройки громкости", 20, 300, 100, 800, 600, "Black", self.volume_custom)

    def inventory(self):
        self.lbl11.close()
        self.btn31.close()
        self.btn1.close()
        self.lbl1.close()
        self.inv.close()
        self.inv_open.show()
        self.btn4.show()
        self.mg_open.close()
        self.btn5.close()
        self.btn6.close()

    def inventory_close(self):
        self.lbl11.show()
        self.btn1.show()
        self.lbl1.show()
        self.inv.show()
        self.inv_open.close()
        self.btn4.close()
        self.notes_open.close()
        self.btn9.close()
        self.mg_open.show()
        self.btn5.show()
        self.btn6.close()
        self.btn7.close()
        self.btn8.close()
        self.easter_open.close()
        self.btn10.close()
        self.btn11.close()
        self.tasks_open.close()
        self.btn31.show()

    def animations(self):
        animation = QPropertyAnimation(self)
        animation.setTargetObject(self.btn_name)
        animation.setPropertyName(b'pos')
        animation.setStartValue(QPoint(250, -200))
        animation.setEndValue(QPoint(250, 0))
        animation.setDuration(500)
        animation.start()

    def event_log(self):
        self.lbl11.close()
        self.btn31.close()
        self.btn1.close()
        self.lbl1.close()
        self.inv.close()
        self.btn5.close()
        self.mg_open.close()
        self.lbl20.show()
        self.btn6.show()
        self.btn7.show()
        self.btn8.show()

    def notes(self):
        self.lbl11.close()
        self.lbl20.close()
        self.notes_open.show()
        self.btn9.show()
        self.btn6.close()
        self.btn7.close()
        self.btn8.close()

    def easter(self):
        self.lbl11.close()
        self.lbl20.close()
        self.easter_open.show()
        self.btn10.show()
        self.btn6.close()
        self.btn7.close()
        self.btn8.close()

    def tasks(self):
        self.lbl11.close()
        self.lbl20.close()
        self.tasks_open.show()
        self.btn11.show()
        self.btn6.close()
        self.btn7.close()
        self.btn8.close()

    def start(self):
        self.lbl11.show()
        self.btn_next.close()
        self.btn1.show()
        self.lbl1.show()
        self.inv.show()
        self.inv_open.close()
        self.btn4.close()
        self.notes_open.close()
        self.btn9.close()
        self.mg_open.show()
        self.btn5.show()
        self.btn6.close()
        self.btn7.close()
        self.btn8.close()
        self.easter_open.close()
        self.btn10.close()
        self.btn11.close()
        self.tasks_open.close()
        self.btn31.show()
        self.lbl2.show()
        self.slider.close()
        self.btn_select.close()
        self.btn_start.close()

    def volume_custom(self):
        sender = self.sender()
        print(f'def volume_custom(): {sender.text()} - {sender.isChecked()}')

        if sender.isChecked():
            self.slider.show()
        else:
            self.slider.close()

        sender.setText(f'Настройки громкости: ({self.slider.value()})')

    def next_start(self):
        #тут действие нужно
        print()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    app.setWindowIcon(QtGui.QIcon('System_image/icon.png'))
    ex = MainWindow()
    ex.setWindowTitle('Story Telling')
    ex.setWindowIcon(QIcon('System_image/icon.png'))
    ex.showFullScreen()
    ex.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: я обновил вопрос и добавил картинку и ещё кое что

Comment: TFader, я насчитал у вас `13 - QPushButton`, `10 - QLabel` и `QSlider`, а вы показали только `ТРИ` кнопки. Я же вам говорил, что `надо показать ВСЕ`.

Comment: Я немного не так понял вас в прошлый раз, и добавил 3 кнопки, сейчас я написал все кнопки и картинки

Comment: @S.Nick, что то не так?

Comment: TFader, я посмотрю ваш код, как только будет время. Вы пока разместите на ваш скриншот все виджеты, которые вы описали, примерно где они у вас располагаются.

Comment: @S.Nick, я прикрепил ссылку на все скриншоты, буду ждать вашего ответа!